# Расставьте пожалуйста запятые?

Tags: пунктуация

Мы дарим Вам этот домик и хотим чтобы все Ваши дома собирались так же легко, как этот дом

Comment: Для начала, слово "пожалуйста" тоже берется в запятые

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мы дарим Вам этот домик и хотим, чтобы все Ваши дома собирались так же легко, как этот дом

Comment: перед как почему запятая нужна?

Comment: Составной союз "так..., как" пишется с запятой перед "как"